# Eclipse: Reading a package in a different folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Either I am entering the wrong words to get a search for this but I was wondering if I could have a Java Package in a folder that isn't in Eclipse's SRC folder but still be able to see it in there much like adding a shortcut to the SRC.

Reason why I ask this is because I am a student and doing work on School PC's to Own PC and back is a bit awkward, even going from School PCA to School PCB is awkward so I thought of having the package I am working in for my assignments and homework to be in my school give OneDrive folder or even in my own private GitHub. I first thought of just making a shortcut from the folder in my OneDrive and putting it into my SRC folder but that just gives Eclipse and LNK file which gives windings text when opening it.

If it is plugin based I may not be able to do it because naturally school PC's really restrict your privileges on installing programs or addons, naturally.

Comment: If you can access your Github (or just git) repository in school na private PC then I'd recommend you to use git

Answer (score 1):

You have to synchronize your School PC package folder(s) in OneDrive and make them auto synchronized with OneDrive in your another-pc/home under a folder.

1. Then you can use that folder as your project src folder of the IDE(assuming different than the previous pc)

or

2. Darg and drop auto downloaded package/java files to the IDE's project src folder.

If this doesn't help, maybe I didn't understand your question properly. Can you provide me with more information - like your -
-> 2nd pc(s) IDE name you will be using. (I am assuming PC-A IDE is eclipse)

I think I can help, it seems I have a similar setup like that.